# Get Base64 image from gallery with cordova

Tags: cordova, base64, filereader

I'm trying to get a base64 image from the phone gallery using cordova.

So far, I get this code :

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    imageURI => {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, 
        fileEntry => {
          fileEntry.file( function(file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = function(evt:any) {
                  // uploadProfileImage needs a base64 image
                  uploadProfileImage(evt.target.result);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }, 
          err => {
            console.log("error file", err)
          });
        },
        err => {
          console.error("error file entry",err);
        }
      )
    },
    err => {
      console.error("error get picture", err)
    }, 
    {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }
  );
```

I've got no error, but the callback onloadend on my FileReader is never called.
I also tried to listen to onerror, onabort, onload, onloadstart or onprogress events : nothing.
reader.readAsDataURL is called but nothing happens next.

Could you help me see where I'm wrong ?

Thanks